# Boolean Won't Change State

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm working on a really simple game like the impossible game but with randomly generated levels. I want them all to be doable, so I though of a system where I have a collider set to be a trigger that I put a script on checking to see if there is Another platform inside of it and then changing a bool called `doable` to `true`. But it simply won't switch it over.

Collision checking scipt:

```
public bool doable = false;

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Platform"))
    {
        doable = true;
    }
}
```

[image: Here's the unity view of things. The platform it self is tagged with "Platform".]
Here's the unity view of things. The platform it self is tagged with "Platform".

Comment: Is the collision matrix set properly?

Comment: @Philipp  probably not since I havn't touched it, but it is all filled in. I don't Know if that's causing anyproblems so if you d oplease tell me.

Comment: I think in Unity the Trigger is only getting invoked when one of the objects has an RigidBody attached to it. Does one of them have an RigidBody?

Comment: hello, sry for no direct solution to your problem, but have you thought about constructing the level as doable right from the beginning? since you know the maximum velocities and gravity you should be able to figure out two limiting parabolas (no-jump and max jump), everything inbetween should be doable (if im not mistaken). because, if you only check later, in the worst (even if not very likely) case you could happen to create infinite not-doable levels.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Platform have a collider attached as well? Make sure that the platform collider is not set to be a trigger. Is the platform on the correct layer such that your collision matrix is filled in correctly?